# Can I pause DBCP while performing DB maintenance?

Tags: h2, apache-commons-dbcp

I have DBCP managing connections for a given h2 DB that during the night needs to be shut down and brought back up again. The time taken is quite quick, during this time I'd like to pause DBCP from lending connections and then when I and finished resume the pool.

I can entertain using a different connection pool, though; use with c3p0 and HikariCP did cause problems elsewhere.

What I wish to achieve is to pause lending, shut down the DB then replace the DB files with new copies, then resume the pool which should automatically restart the h2 db.

Answer (score 0):

BoneCP may have a feature that allows this type of extended disconnect while the underlying database is restarted as it can replay transactions if a connection fails, but it would mean that the application has been coded to operate with transactions. I do not know the feature myself but the 0.6.5 release notes state the floowing

> The main feature is the automatic replay of a transaction whereby all activity on a transaction (from BEGIN TRANSACTION to COMMIT/ROLLBACK) is saved. Should a recoverable exception occur, for example if the database fails or the network goes down, the pool will automatically play back all of the transaction, letting your application recover gracefully and automatically.

Otherwise the best option would be to move the connection management up to the application code so that when a connection ends up being reported as broken to application can pause and retry before erroring out.